# Reading data through XML file tag and inseting newline while outputting to outlook

Tags: python

I have the following data in an XML file which i am reading using the below mentioned python code and then writing that to outlook,when its written to outlook I see all the data gets printed in one line..I want to print one line after the other,I tried to use "br" tag in the xml file at the end of everyline,wrap each line around "br"and "/br" but nothing seems to work,any suggestions?
XML

```
<rel_notes>
    1.)Please move to this build for all further test and development 
    activities .
    2.)Please use this as a basebuild to verify 
    compilation and sanity
    3.)Any CL that nees to be integrated must 
    have a CL
</rel_notes>
```

Python code

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse(file)
Releasenotes = ('\n'.join(elem.text for elem in tree.iter('rel_notes')))
```

OUTPUT

```
Release notes: 1.)Please move to this build for all further test and development activities 2.)Please use this as a basebuild to verify compilation and sanity 3.)Any CL that nees to be integrated must have a CL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the standard XML Python lib, but [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) which is more powerful (support of XPath, etc). It looks like it works basically as you wish:

```
>>> s = """<rel_notes>
    1.)Please move to this build for all further test and development 
    activities .
    2.)Please use this as a basebuild to verify 
    compilation and sanity
    3.)Any CL that nees to be integrated must 
    have a CL
</rel_notes>"""
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.fromstring(s)
>>> root.text
'\n    1.)Please move to this build for all further test and development \n    activities .\n    2.)Please use this as a basebuild to verify \n    compilation and sanity\n    3.)Any CL that nees to be integrated must \n    have a CL\n'
>>> print root.text

    1.)Please move to this build for all further test and development 
    activities .
    2.)Please use this as a basebuild to verify 
    compilation and sanity
    3.)Any CL that nees to be integrated must 
    have a CL

>>>
```